# AWS S3 `--exclude` being ignored

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I can't make `--exclude` work on AWS S3. Neither of the three versions of the commands work. No matter how I exclude the directories, they are still being uploaded.

```
root@taurus [/]# aws s3 sync / s3://server.taurus  --exclude "disk3/*" --exclude "backup/*"

root@taurus [/]# aws s3 sync / s3://server.taurus  --exclude 'disk3/*' --exclude 'backup/'

root@taurus [/]# aws s3 sync / s3://server.taurus  --exclude 'disk3/' --exclude 'backup/'
```

Please see my AWS CLI version below.

```
root@taurus [/]# aws --version
aws-cli/1.10.14 Python/2.6.6 Linux/2.6.32-531.29.2.lve1.3.11.1.el6.x86_64.debug botocore/1.4.5
root@taurus [/]#
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: What is shown, if you try your `aws s3 sync` command with the `--dryrun` **and** `--debug` options?

Answer (score 1):

From the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) documentation for the [sync command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html):

> `--include` (string) Don't exclude files or objects in the command that match the specified pattern. See [Use of Exclude and Include Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters) for details.
>
> `--exclude` (string) Exclude all files or objects from the command that matches the specified pattern.

So (strange as it may seem), you must must specify objects to `--include` AND objects to `--exclude`. Using `--include *` is acceptable.

Specifying `--exclude` on its own will not match any files.